# Why can't I access the object using the arrow operator

Tags: c++, pointers

Suppose I have

```
struct B
{
  template<typename T>
  void doSomething(T& bar); 
};


class A
{
  //... (ctor etc.)

  template<typename T>
  void foo(const std::string& name, T& bar)
  {
    for(auto& data : myData)
    {
      if(data.first == name)
        *(data.second)->doSomething(bar); //ERROR
    }
  }

private:
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, B**>> myData;

};
```

I thought this would work because we are iterating over 'myData' by reference, i.e. no copies, and then we do `*(data.second)` to access a pointer to `B`, which we then use the '`>` operator to access its '`oSomething` Method.

Instead, I am just getting the error:

**member reference base type 'B*' is not a structure or union**

which makes no sense to me since B* is a pointer to a struct, and using the '->' operator on that would dereference the pointer revealing the actual class.

GodBolt Reproduction: https://godbolt.org/z/c45oMT

Comment: `Struct` -> `struct`... Typo in question only? Please [edit] your question to include a proper [mcve] without unrelated problems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I feel this example is quite minimal and well explains my problem. Fixed the type

Comment: `*(A)->B` means `*((A)->B)` because "->" has higher precendence

Answer (score 3):

And the error mentioned in the question is because `*(data.second)->doSomething(bar)` is really the same as `*(data.second->doSomething(bar))`.

That is you try to call `data.second->doSomething(bar)` which is not possible because `data.second` is a pointer to a pointer to an object.

Then you attempt to dereference whatever `doSomething` returns, which also isn't possible since it doesn't return anything.

What you *probably* want is something like

```
(*data.second)->doSomething(bar);
```

This will first dereference `data.second` removing one indirection, resulting in a pointer to `B` (i.e. `*data.second` results in a `B*`). Then call the function on that object.

Comment: Indeed, that was the error, thank you for the resolution.